# How to change Solution Configuration to fix Error MSB4126 on Travis CI?

Tags: c#, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm trying to adopt Continuous Integration practices in a development project I'm working on, so I'm making use of Travis CI. The project I'm working on is a game that builds perfectly in Visual Studio. But after pushing any change I make on GitHub, when Travis tries to build it, it always fails. Below is the error message I get in the Job Log on Travis CI.

> Build started 11/11/2018 11:59:03 AM.
>   Project "/home/travis/build/Jeryxem/Escapade/MyGameWin.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
>   /home/travis/build/Jeryxem/Escapade/MyGameWin.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Release|x86" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration. [/home/travis/build/Jeryxem/Escapade/MyGameWin.sln]
>   Done Building Project "/home/travis/build/Jeryxem/Escapade/MyGameWin.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
>   Build FAILED.

My `.travis.yml` file has only this in it:

```
language: csharp
solution: Escapade.sln
```

Per some research I've made, I'm thinking that I need to edit my `csproj` file to change the Platform and/or Configuration details. Below is the full content of my `csproj` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug-Windows</Configuration>
    <ProjectGuid>{A9DCAC72-BC77-4C33-BE70-BBFD31D7C798}</ProjectGuid>
    <RootNamespace>Escapade</RootNamespace>
    <MonoMacResourcePrefix>Resources</MonoMacResourcePrefix>
    <AssemblyName>Escapade</AssemblyName>
    <SuppressXamMacUpsell>True</SuppressXamMacUpsell>
    <SuppressXamMacMigration>True</SuppressXamMacMigration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <ApplicationIcon>Resources\SwinGame.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug-Windows|x86' ">
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <EnableCodeSigning>false</EnableCodeSigning>
    <CreatePackage>false</CreatePackage>
    <EnablePackageSigning>false</EnablePackageSigning>
    <IncludeMonoRuntime>false</IncludeMonoRuntime>
    <UseSGen>false</UseSGen>
    <UseRefCounting>false</UseRefCounting>
    <Profiling>false</Profiling>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PrepareForRunDependsOn>$(PrepareForRunDependsOn);CopyLibsToOut</PrepareForRunDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Resources\panels\meta.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="SwinGame">
      <HintPath>lib\SwinGame.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config" />
    <WinLibs Include="lib\win32\*.dll" />
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\overlay_diamond.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\overlay_emerald.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\overlay_ruby.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\overlay_sapphire.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_east.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_inner_1.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_inner_2.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_inner_3.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_north.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_northeast.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_northwest.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_south.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_southeast.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_southwest.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_vertex_northeast.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_vertex_northwest.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_vertex_southeast.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_vertex_southwest.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_wall_horiz.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_wall_vert.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_west.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\animations\startup.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\bundles\FileDialog.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\bundles\splash.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\fonts\arial.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\fonts\cour.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\fonts\maven_pro_regular.ttf">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\fdFile.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\fdFolder.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\FileDialog_Active.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\FileDialog_Background.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\FileDialog_Inactive.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\FileDialog_Scroll.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\FileDialog_ScrollSmall.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\Swinburne.jpg">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\SwinGameAni.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\panels\FileDialog.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\sounds\error.wav">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\sounds\SwinGameStart.wav">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\SwinGame.icns">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\SwinGame.ico">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_pointnorth.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_pointsouth.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_pointwest.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="Resources\images\tiles\rock_pointeast.png">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Countdown.cs" />
    <Compile Include="GameLevel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\Entry.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\gui\MetaHandler.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\Location.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\mineral\gemstone\Sapphire.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\mineral\gemstone\Ruby.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\mineral\gemstone\Emerald.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\mineral\gemstone\Diamond.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\mineral\gemstone\Gemstone.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\mineral\Mineral.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\MovableObject.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\Entity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\Path.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\PathNode.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\Player.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\Tile.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\TileType.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\World.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\Item.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\Inventory.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\gui\GuiEnvironment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\gui\Renderer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\gui\Frame.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\gui\GuiEvent.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\Escapade.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\BitmapMask.cs" />
    <Compile Include="src\gui\Button.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Weapon.cs" />
    <Compile Include="WeaponType.cs" />
    <Compile Include="AttackDirection.cs" />
    <Compile Include="GlobalConstants.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Enemy.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Projectile.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <Target Name="CopyLibsToOut">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(WinLibs)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

What do I need to change to make sure my solution can build without any errors on Travis CI? Any idea how to provide a valid solution configuration so that I don't get Error MSB4126 anymore?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? because i am facing same problem with my web app.

Comment: I wasn't able to solve the issue with Travis CI, so I ended up using Jenkins, which worked fine.

Comment: ok, Thank you for reply...

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred recently for with NET6.0, and it is worth posting the solution. It wasn't really related to the error description. In Travis-CI, I normally have a BUILD_CONFIG setting which is release for master and release branches, and debug for the development branch.  My .travis.yml file has

```
script:
- chmod +x ./deploy.sh 
- ./deploy.sh
```

The deploy.sh file has this line to launch the build: it was written for dotnetcore, but works as well for NET5 and NET6.

```
dotnet build -c $BUILD_CONFIG BOG.DropZone
```

I was getting this error because I was building the develop branch which did not have a definition for the environment variable BUILD_CONFIG.  So it was executing "dotnet build -c  BOG.DropZone" which can generate all kinds of weird errors.

When I added the environment variable for the develop branch (BUILD_CONFIG = debug), the command line worked correctly.  The subsequent build gave me another error with a folder name case mismatch (Debug versus debug) in the project file, but it was a real error.  I fixed that, and now it works fine.

Seems like this problem has eluded a lot of people.  My first clue should have been that my project Name was in the error (error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "BOG.DropZone|Any CPU" is invalid).

Hope this helps.  FWIW: The .travis.yml and deploy.sh files are in this solution (build an app, and two nuget packages).

[BOG.DropZone on github.com](https://github.com/rambotech/BOG.DropZone/tree/develop)